# Plotly displayed nothing when using for loop in a notebook

Tags: python, for-loop, plot, plotly

The idea is  to plot and get the following figure.

[image]

The following code were used to get the above

```
from random import randint
import plotly.graph_objects as go


x1 = [randint(0, 9) for p in range(0, 10)]
x2 = [randint(0, 9) for p in range(0, 10)]
x3 = [randint(0, 9) for p in range(0, 10)]

time=list(range(0, len(x1))) 

fig = go.Figure()


fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=time, y=x1,
                    mode='lines',
                    name='X1'))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=time, y=x2,
                    mode='lines',
                    name='X2'))


fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=time, y=x3,
                    mode='lines',
                    name='X3'))
```

But, to make the code more efficient, I tried something like this which I got from this [link](https://community.plot.ly/t/when-using-plotly-inside-a-loop-nothing-is-printed/5839)

Data=[x1,x2,x3]  ## This maybe wrong

```
   for i in range(0,2):
      trace = go.Scatter( x = times,
                               y = data[:, i],
                               mode = 'markers+lines'
                             )
```

Nothing come up whenever I tried to use for loop to plot a graph using plotly.

Appreciate for any help.
Thanks

Comment: when I run `for`-loop in notebook then I have to still use `fig.add_trace()`. And  `fig.show()` after loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why first version shows without `fig.show()` but sencond not but mostly using `matplotlib` or `plotly` or other module (in script, python's shell or notebook) I have to use `fig.show()` (or `plt.show()` for `matplotlib`) to see plot.

After changing few mistakes - `y = data[i]` instead of `y = data[:, i]` and `range(3)` instead of`range(0, 2)` - this code works for me in `notebook`

```
from random import randint
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x1 = [randint(0, 9) for p in range(10)]
x2 = [randint(0, 9) for p in range(10)]
x3 = [randint(0, 9) for p in range(10)]

time = list(range(len(x1))) 

data = [x1, x2, x3] 

fig = go.Figure()

for i in range(3):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=time, y=data[i], mode='markers+lines', name='X{}'.format(i)))

fig.show()
```

Comment: In the first version, the final result of the cell is a figure, which auto-shows. Within a for loop or in an if block or function, this isn’t the case and show() is required.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and explanation. I work perfectly